# Does an if statement inherit tense of the preceding one?

Tags: grammar

Here's my example that i want to check:

> "i would have got it even if u wrote it in hexadecimal  "

Is it grammatically correct? or should "**had written**" be used instead of "**wrote**"?

Comment: If you intend to use lower-case "i" and "u" instead of "you" then there's nothing so terribly wrong with the rest of the sentence.  If you want to write it in a more literate style, however, it definitely needs some work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with "had written" versus "wrote", but "have got" is also an issue. The sentence should read, "I would have gotten it even if you had written in it in hexadecimal." See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_perfect. Perhaps other users will be able to provide more definitive references.

Addendum: According to the section on **third conditionals** in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences, when the conditional ("if") clause is **past perfect**, the consequence ("then") clause is **conditional perfect**. That reference  gives these two examples:

- If you had called me, I would have come.
- Would he have succeeded if I had helped him?

Comment: Does this mean that wrote is absolutely incorrect and can not be accepted?

Comment: @caddy Yes, because it's a hypothetical regarding an event that took place in the past. I'll look it up a grammatical reference and add it to the answer.

Comment: @Caddy Not necessarily. Consider the case where 'have got' is changed to 'get': *I would get it even if [you] wrote it in hexadecimal*.

Comment: Note that British English (at least) does not customarily have *gotten* and "I would have got it" is correct.